Optimizing Image Loading on flutter for Simultaneous Rendering
I want to load and render all images on the Instagram category screen at the same time, rather than loading them separately one by one. How can I achieve this? this is Instagram loading image and render at same time

like this and this not like this
this is my output

I have a GET API that fetches network images, which are displayed using a ListView.builder with caching. Currently, the images load one by one or random, but I want to load all the images at once and render them at same time like instagram search feed screen. Additionally, I want to show a CircularProgressIndicator until all the images have finished loading. How can I achieve this?
SizedBox(
      width: 14.6.w,
      height: 14.6.w,
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: chat.image, // Handle URL here
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
            Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: imageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        placeholder: (context, url) => Skeletonizer(
          ignoreContainers: true,
          enabled: true,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.h),
            width: 14.6.w,
            height: 14.6.w,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(CommonFunctions
                        .dummyImageUrl))),
          ),
        ),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
            const Icon(Icons.error),
      ),
    ),

